# Incorrect frequency in FFT spectogram

Tags: python-3.x, audio, fft, librosa, spectrogram

I created a 114dB 1KHz signal and wanted to plot a power spectrum with librosa stft. But I see in the low frequencies in the spectrum and also see peaks at other frequencies. I am unsure what am I doing wrong here.
Plot here -> [FFT spectrum, Power avg plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwOvy.png)

```
y, sr = librosa.load('Noise Recorder (RMS)_APxRecordedAudio.wav',sr=None,duration=10) 
print(y.shape, sr)
# Plot 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr, ax=ax[0,0])
n_fft = 8192    # FFT Length
S = librosa.stft(y=y,n_fft=n_fft,win_length=n_fft,hop_length=n_fft,window='hann')     # Short FFT
F = librosa.fft_frequencies(sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft) # Frequency components
Abs = np.abs(S)  # Same as mag, phase = librosa.magphase(S)
Abs_mean = np.mean(Abs, axis = 1)   # Mean
Power_avg =librosa.power_to_db(Abs_mean**2) # dB
Scale_dB = 86.85    # Scaling factor
Power_Scaled_dB = Power_avg + Scale_dB     # Scaled dB # Max: 114dB
```

Comment: If your wave does not begin _and_ end on a zero crossing you will have a discontinuity which will result in extra frequency content. The hann window should take care of the ends of your audio file, but it depends on which samples the actually wave begins and ends. Your spectrogram suggests the noise is coming from the start of the file.

Comment: A time plot over that duration will just show a block. It would probably be more useful to try and plot the first and last ~100 samples before and after windowing.

Comment: Finally, you mention the wave was 114dB which suggests it came from an analogue source. You may get noise from the recording process. Try generating the same wave purely digitally to see the difference.